# Tokens and how to handle them

Tags: android

I'm developping an app that pulls and push data to a server.

To prevent undesired use of the webservices, we settled a token system that renews every once in a while.

I'm creating a method that would check before every webservices calls if the token is not null.

Something like :

```
public boolean isTokenValid(){
    if (token == null){
        renewToken();
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Same fashion if I get server error code that the token is expired I'd call `renewToken()`

**My question :**

How do I have my method to be called again when receiving the valid token ? Keep in mind the method called after is "dynamic" : the method could be called from any webservice and therefore require it to run this very call again.

**Potential solutions :**

1) Create as many method of token renewal as the webservices.

For eg : renewTokenGetProduct(), renewTokenGetProfile()... to know which webservice to call when getting valid token. But that seems rather inapropriate.

2) I could also be passing a parameter. For example renewToken(PRODUCT) or renewToken(PROFILE) and then use conditions or broadcast but it seemed to me a bit overkill/sloppy again.

Answer (score 1):

From api side try to add one more parameter with the token.

Like token and category.

so

```
public boolean isTokenValid(){
if (token == null){
    renewToken();
    return false;
}
return true;
}
```

then in renew token:

```
if(category.equals("profile"){
  //do necessary work
}
else if(category.equals("product"){
  //do necessary work or pass intent
}
else{
  //
}
```